# Automatically incrementing a number in a "for loop"

Tags: javascript, function, loops, increment

I have this code:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i += 2) {
     sum += i;
};
console.log(sum);
```

I want to be able to create a function to allows someone to change the increment number without having to directly change it in the code. I know a start might be:

```
function sumFactor(factor) {};
```

but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Change the "2" to "factor"...?

Answer (score 1):

This what you are looking for...?

```
function sumFactor(factor) {
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i+= factor) {
    sum += i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Pass in your increment value:

```
function sumFactor(factor) {

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 51; i += factor) {
         sum += i;
    }
    console.log(sum);
};

//Then call your function
sumFactor(2);
```